# What is a good report generation (i.e. PDF reports) that can be used with Objective-C on mac?

Tags: objective-c, pdf-generation, report

I am creating a program for mac that needs to generate reports and be able to print them as PDF files. I would rather find an already created library for this rather than hard-coding everything, but I can't find anything yet. Do you recommend any report generation libraries that can be used in Objective-C?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked at it in a pretty long time, but you might want to check out ReportMill.  It goes way back to the NeXTSTEP days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are online and can call a web service, then you can get [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) to produce a PDF report and deliver it wherever.  I've seen this done in objectve-c from an iPad.